# Interfacing switch and LED

Tags: led, c, interface

I am trying to write a program in which I am interfacing a switch and a LED. I want a program so that when I press the switch the LED turns on and when I press again that led turns off. Right now I have made a program in which when I press the switch the LED turns on and then goes off.

```
void main()
{
    DDRA=0x01;  // Interfacing LED at PORTA.0
    DDRB=0xFE; // Interfacing Switch at PORTB.0
    PORTB=0xFF;

    while(1)
    {
        if(PINB==0xFE)
        {
            PORTA=0x01;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTA=0x00;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is switch and not a push button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you are dealing with a push button and not a switch. So `Pin0` on `PORTB (PB0)` stays LOW as long as you are pushing the button, the `if statement` is fulfilled and your LED will be turned on. But once you release the button, `PB0` will go back HIGH and the `else branch` will be executed, thus your LED will be turned off immediately.

You need an additional variable, which changes only on button **pushes** and remains unchanged on button **releases**. Then you can control the LED with this variable.

Example:

```
void main()
{
    DDRA |= (1<<PA0);               // Set first PIN on PORTA as output (LED)
    DDRB &= ~(1<<PB0);              // Set first PIN on PORTB as input  (BUTTON)

    uint8_t status = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(!(PINB & (1<<PB0)))      // check if first PIN on PORTB is not HIGH, button pushed
        {
            status = !status;     
        }

        if(status)
        {
            PORTA |= (1<<PA0);    // Set first PIN on PORTA
        }
        else
        {
            PORTA &= ~(1<<PA0);   // Clear first PIN on PORTA
        }
    }
}
```

In addition have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c) about bit operations. Very useful when you want to change only one bit on a PORT and let the rest unchanged.

A simpler soultion is to toggle the LED controller pin itself on button pushes. To do so,  the XOR operator: `^` could be used as follows `PORTA ^= (1<<PA0)`. This means that we XOR `1`(HIGH) with the current value of the PIN.

- If the LED is on, the current value of the PIN is  `1` (HIGH), which we XOR with another `1`. The result will be `1 XOR 1 = 0` so the LED will be turned off.
- Now, when the LED is off, the current value of the PIN is `0` (LOW), which we XOR with `1` again. The result will be `0 XOR 1 = 1` so the LED will be turned on.

Example:

```
void main()
{
    DDRA |= (1<<PA0);               // Set first PIN on PORTA as output (LED)
    DDRB &= ~(1<<PB0);              // Set first PIN on PORTB as input  (BUTTON)

    while(1)
    {
        if(!(PINB & (1<<PB0)))      // check if first PIN on PORTB is not HIGH, button pushed
        {
            PORTA ^= (1<<PA0);     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks friend. That solved my problem and I got the logic